# Can't launch VS Code from Windows Terminal inside WSL 2

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal, scoop-installer

I installed VS Code using the Scoop package manager.

I get this error when launching VS Code from Windows Terminal, inside WSL 2:

[image: WSL 2 VS Code launch error]

My theory is that the error is caused because I used Scoop instead of the regular installer.

Should I use the regular VS Code installer from their website or can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I uninstalled VS Code using Scoop and installed the regular installer from the VS Code website and now it works.

Seems the problem is with the Scoop VS Code installer.

[image]

Comment: Check out this Github Issue for the cause: https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop-extras/issues/2581

Comment: And this for the fix - https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop-extras/issues/2581#issuecomment-623868510 - see how to replace the shim.